# How to find whether a Table in SQLite contains data or not

Tags: android

I have created a SQLite database & table in Android.
After performing all the necessary calculations , I have deleted the data from the table of the database by calling the below code.

**sampleDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + Constants.TABLE_NAME);**

Now , I need to write a condition to check that if no data is there for that particular table , I need to show an Alert .

I am unable to find the code to check the condition whether data is there or not for the TABLE , maybe how to check the size of the data within the TABLE.

Kindly provide hints/sample code.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397757/how-can-i-check-to-see-if-my-sqlite-table-has-data-in-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table;
```