# check if database is empty in android

Tags: android, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i check to see if my sqlite table has data in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397757/how-can-i-check-to-see-if-my-sqlite-table-has-data-in-it)
>   [Android check if database is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251901/android-check-if-database-is-empty)

Can anybody tell me how to check if sqlite database (in android) is empty or has tables and if it has tables is it empty or has values?

I made a login authentication program using sqlite and I want it to check if there is no users to log in automatically

Comment: This is an odd request... Normally you would already have a SQLite database with a table structure, in which case it becomes trivial to check for the presence of records in the table.

Comment: to check weather there is an empty table or not , you can use row count of Sqlite

Comment: You have already asked this question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251901/android-check-if-database-is-empty

Answer (score 1):

You can make a simple method checking if database alredy exists.

```
private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch(SQLiteException e){ 
        //database doesn't exist yet
    }

    if(checkDB != null){
        checkDB.close();
    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}
```